# Error while passing parameter to scala sbt from command line

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to run SBT project with some parameter.

```
sbt -Dbootstrap=true run
```

However, I'm getting following error.

```
Warning: invalid system property 'bootstrap'
[error] Not a valid command: true (similar: start)
[error] Not a valid project ID: true
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: true (similar: run, runner, target)
[error] true
[error]     ^
```

I tried adding `scalacOptions += "-feature"` in build.sbt, the invalid system property 'bootstrap' is gone, but the error is still persisting.

Comment: do you want to launch your application with this system property set?

Comment: yes, I need to run with this property set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run your application with specific system property set use the setting `javaOptions` property in your sbt build file as shown below.

```
javaOptions in run += "-Dbootstrap=true"
```

Also set fork option to true to launch a new JVM process for each run. `javaOptions` settings are honored only when the fork option is set.

```
fork := true
```

now the command to run the application would simply be `sbt run`

Comment: Its not working for me. I am unable to get value of bootstrap on GlobalSetting class. The value is none instead of true. I'm catching parameter value in GlobalSetting class onStart() function, app.configuration.getBoolean("bootstrap").

Comment: make sure you rerun `reload`, `clean` before `run`. if the issue still exists try `javaOptions in Global` instead of  `javaOptions in run`

Comment: @RaKa did you try setting fork = true as updated in the answer?